# Date format dd/mm in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I use SQL Server and I need to display a `datetime` data type in the following format:

```
dd/mm
```

day-month without the year, which is the most effective way?

Comment: try `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 3) `

Comment: thanks, it's the most effective way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `103` style in `convert` function and remove the `year`

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), Getdate(), 103), 5) --11/03
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll find this site really helpful I think:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

From that link, you can see this as a quick way to get DD/MM:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 3) AS [DD/MM]
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I edited to include the specific response from the link.